# Finding Upper and Lower limits using four vertices of a Trapezoid

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need a little help with finding upper and lower limits of the below equation using four vertices of a Trapezoid. The four vertices are upper left$(1,3)$, upper right$(5,3)$, lower left$(2,1)$, and lower right$(4,1)$.

The equation is: 
$$\iint xy \mathop{\mathrm{d}A}.$$

I know that $\mathrm dA$ = $\mathrm dy \mathrm dx$ and I can double integrate the equation on my own after I've found the limits, finding limits is where I'm having problem at, so if anyone can help me calculate the limits or point me in the right directions to do that I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You want  $ \iint d x^2 \cdot \, d y^2/4 $$, squared numbers for limits can be also used.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Simply choose one variable first, say $x$. Then choose that variable for the outer integral. The range for this variable is just the range needed to cover the whole region. For the inner integral, compute the possible range of the other variable, say $y$, which might of course depend on $x$. Of course, you may have to split into cases, and if so you have to split the integral into parts, one for each case. Those ranges are of course the 'limits' of the integrals that you're looking for. If you find using $x$ for the outer integral troublesome, then try using $y$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm finiding it quite confusing. Do you mean to say that the limit of outer integral should be x(or y) to 0, x being the upper and 0 being the lower limit?

Comment: @Kraken: No. An integral is always over some variable, is it not? If you want to use a doubly-nested integral to compute an integral over an area, don't you want one integral over $x$ and one over $y$? The limits of an integral is simply the range over which you integrate. I'm suspecting you don't actually understand integration. Is that the case?

Comment: I do understand integration, it's just a bit confusing for me at times. I'm good at questions which have pre-defined limits, but in this question limits have to be found first so I'm stuck at it. What I understood by seeing the figure was that the outer integral's limit should be 5 to 1, and inner integral's limit should be 3 to 1, but after reading a bit on it online it seemed to be wrong.

Comment: @Kraken: I tried a while but couldn't find a good explanation with diagrams.. Try http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DoubleIntegrals.aspx and the next page after that.

Comment: @Kraken: Your comment does show that you do not understand integration. Your understanding is not about integration but about finding anti-derivatives, namely something whose derivative is what you're given. That is related but distinct from integration. Integration in this context is about area under the curve or volume under a surface, so the link I gave might help. However, it doesn't explain clearly what the limits mean so you should try to figure that out yourself and get back to me again if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kraken: I don't have the time to draw diagrams, but basically think of how **you** would approximate the volume using cuboids.. the position of the cuboids is determined by the region, and when you sum over cuboids between positions $p$ and $q$ and use sufficiently narrow cuboids, the result is approximately the integral over the interval $[p,q]$ by **definition** of the integral as the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula point-slope form i.e. $(y-y_1) = \frac{(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)}\cdot (x-x_1)$.

Use the above formula for all the vertices.